# Docker can not access external database server

Tags: sql-server, linux, docker, centos

I have an asp.net core that connects to a SQL Server. When I run it in docker on my local computer everything works as expected, but when run the docker image on a linux server (centos 8) i get a network error when trying to connect to the database. I don't know what to do, since I used the actual server's ip in the connection string and it still does not work. 
Thank you a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should configure the firewall correct and watch if SELinux is blocking you in some way.

Just to speed up your testing, try after these commands:

```
sudo su -
systemctl disable firewalld
setenforce 0
```

Comment: Between your CentOS and SQL Server there is no Firewall? Are you running the commands as root? I mean... the docker ones.

Comment: the firewall was off and it still didn't work. 

it started working after running this commands on the centos machine, with the firewall off:

sysctl net.ipv4.conf.all.forwarding=1
sudo iptables -P FORWARD ACCEPT

Comment: Yeah :/ forgot about that, sorry